# Google InfoWindow not loading inside for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop, google-maps-api-3

I have add the following code to a Google Map on a site of mine.  The map contains many points pulling from coordinates set in the WordPress backend.

I also want to include some static points which will always stay on the map and am hardcoding their coordinates.

The following is the code I am using and what happens is that the code displays the first marker but not the infobox.  Because of this, the code stops and does not continue through the for loop.  The issue is at the `return function()` bit, but I am not sure how to get it working.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 185});
var setMarker;
var setMarkers = new Array();

var setLocations = [
['<h4>Location1</h4>', 53.4264,-6.2499, '/wp-content/themes/path/to/airport_icon.png'],
['<h4>Location2</h4>', 53.3461,-6.2969, '/wp-content/themes/path/to/train_icon.png'],
['<h4>Location3</h4>', 53.3532,-6.2468, '/wp-content/themes/path/to/train_icon.png'],
['<h4>Location4</h4>', 53.4264,-6.2499, '/wp-content/themes/path/to/dvc_icon.png'],
['<h4>Location5</h4>', 53.4264,-6.2499, '/wp-content/themes/path/to/dvc_icon.png'],
        ];



for (var i = 0; i < setLocations.length; i++) {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(setLocations[i][1], setLocations[i][2]),
                icon : setLocations[i][3],
        });
setMarkers.push(setMarker);

google.maps.event.addListener(setMarker, 'click', (function(setMarker, i) {
                return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(setLocations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, setMarker);
                }
        })(setMarker, i));
}
```

Comment: Where did you define `setMarker`? You are using `marker = new google.maps.Marker()`.

Comment: Hey @MrUpsidown thanks for the reply.  `setMarker` is up above the setLocations in my snippet and yes, I am using `marker = new google.maps.Marker()`, it is in the for loop

Comment: And that's why it's not working... You defined `setMarker` globally (which I would not do) but you are not using it.

Comment: You absolute legend! Thank you so much for that!

Comment: @MrUpsidown I wonder could you throw your eyes over this issue also, I would appreciate it greatly?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666044/markers-not-appearing-on-google-map-using-wp-query-to-find-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `setMarker` variable inside the for loop and push it to your markers array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < setLocations.length; i++) {

    var setMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(setLocations[i][1], setLocations[i][2])
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(setMarker, 'click', (function (setMarker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(setLocations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, setMarker);
        }
    })(setMarker, i));

    setMarkers.push(setMarker);
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/rmp7gjth/)</kbd>