# Markers not appearing on Google Map using wp_query to find points

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the [WP Favorite Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/) plugin to allow users to select their favourite tours on the site.  The posts are saved using to cookies to a saved template provided by the plugin.  I have edited this template to include a map and to pull the coordinates from a Custom Meta Field.

The full template can be found at http://pastebin.com/zDrr5fPn.

The code I have included to display the map is:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>
```

and the code I am using for the loop is:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true) !== '' ) : ?>
                    <div style="display:block;">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function initialize() {
                            //load map
                            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                                  zoom: 9, 
                                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3498, -6.2603), 
                                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                  disableDefaultUI: true
                            });


                            var savedMarkers = new Array();



                             <?php $saved_pos = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true);?>

                                function addMarker() {
                                    var savedMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        map: map,
                                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $saved_pos ?>),
                                        icon: '/wp-content/themes/dublin-visitors-centre/images/saved_icon.png',
                                    });
                                savedMarkers.push(savedMarker);

                                }
                                }
                        </script>
                    </div>
```

At the moment, when I view the source, I can see the points being selected, the coordinates do appear.  However they do not appear on the map itself.  It is as if the points are appearing in the list of saved posts but not on the map at all.

I hope this makes sense.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show the JS output in the DOM?

Comment: Well just a quick update on it, I removed the `function addMarker()` and am getting the last marker to display.  If you go to http://dublinvisitorcentre.ie/things/belvedere-irish-night/, save to favourites on the RHS, then http://dublinvisitorcentre.ie/things/jeanie-johnston-tall-ship-famine-museum/ and save to favourites and finally to http://dublinvisitorcentre.ie/saved, you will see only one item is coming in, which should be your last saved item.

Comment: Please paste the JS that your PHP script outputs in your question.

Comment: This is for one of the markers: http://pastebin.com/EjuVBf8n.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code. Are you doing that in a loop? I can't tell from that bit of code... Are you duplicating the whole code?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes I am doing it in the loop which could be where the issue is.  The full template can be found here - http://pastebin.com/zDrr5fPn

Comment: Thanks again for your help MrUpsidown, I have a working solution below now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop only populate an array with the latitudes/longitudes, create `initialize` outside of the loop:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    //load map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                               zoom: 9, 
                               center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3498, -6.2603), 
                               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                               disableDefaultUI: true
         });
    //create the markers
    for(var i=0;i<savedMarkers.length;++i){
      savedMarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(savedMarkers[i][0],
                                              savedMarkers[i][1]),
             icon: '/wp-content/themes/dublin-visitors-centre/images/saved_icon.png',
           });
    }
  }

<?php
  //create a php-array to store the latitudes and longitudes
  $savedMarkers=array();
    //use the loop to populate the array
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true) !== '' ) : 
        $savedMarkers[]=explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true));
      endif;
    endwhile;
?>
//print the array as js-variable
savedMarkers= <?php echo json_encode($savedMarkers);?>;

</script>
```

It's not tested, there may be some errors, but it should be sufficient to demonstrate the workflow.

---

**Related to the comments:**
To apply the post-title as infowindow-content also store the title in the savedMarkers-items:

```
$savedMarkers[]=array_merge(explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true)),
                            array(get_the_title()));
```

when you create the marker create a custom property for the marker where you store the infowindow-content(let's call the property `content`):

```
//create the markers
for(var i=0;i<savedMarkers.length;++i){
  savedMarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(savedMarkers[i][0],
                                          savedMarkers[i][1]),
         icon: '/wp-content/themes/dublin-visitors-centre/images/saved_icon.png',
          //the content(post-title)
         content: savedMarkers[i][2]
       });
}
```

Now use this content as infowindow-content:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(savedMarkers[i], 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(this.get('content'));
    infowindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
  }
);
```

---

**You may also create a link to the posts inside the infowindows:**

```
$savedMarkers[]=array_merge(explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_latlng', true)),
                            array(get_the_title(),get_permalink()));
```

......

```
//create the markers
for(var i=0;i<savedMarkers.length;++i){
  savedMarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
         map: map,
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(savedMarkers[i][0],
                                          savedMarkers[i][1]),
         icon: '/wp-content/themes/dublin-visitors-centre/images/saved_icon.png',
         //the content(post-title)
         title: '' + savedMarkers[i][2],
         //post-URL
         href: savedMarkers[i][3]
       });
}
```

..........

```
google.maps.event.addListener(savedMarkers[i], 'click', function() {
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.get('title')));
    link.setAttribute('href',this.get('href'));
    infowindow.setContent(link);
    infowindow.open(this.getMap(), this);
  }
);
```

Comment: That seems to have done it for me!  Now all I need to do is add in the infoboxes, but I should be ok with that.  Thanks so much for your help on this!

Comment: Hey @Dr.Molle, I wonder could you have another quick look at this and see what I am missing for the infoboxes?  I plan on just adding in the titles of the markers as infoboxes at the moment.  I have no js errors.  I copied what you did but for a new variable called savedTitles but the infoboxes do not load.  The full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/zDrr5fPn
At the moment, I am just trying to print anything at all in the Infobox and will move onto the title once the infobox works.

Comment: You want to print the complete post-content in the infobox?

Comment: The title of the post would do just fine. That way users can tell by clicking on each marker what point it actually relates to. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hey @Dr.Molle.  This all worked perfectly for me!  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: sorry, It seems as if I forgot to mention the post-edit